# Unmountable Volume BSOD after converting to dynamic disk and mirroring volume

Tags: windows-7, hard-drive, boot, partitioning, bsod

I have a PC with two Western Digital drives connected via SATA with AHCI enabled; one is 500GB, the other is 640GB. My primary boot partition is located on the 500GB drive. I recently formatted the 640GB drive and created a mirrored volume on it; mirroring the primary boot partition. I also converted the partition scheme for the 500GB disk from a basic disk to a dynamic disk. I was able to boot from this configuration a number of times over the course of a week, thus I'm not certain whether creating a mirrored volume is the cause of my issue. That said I can no longer boot from either partition (primary or mirror). I get a Unmountable Volume BSOD every time; The error code is `UNMOUNTABLE_BOOT_VOLUME`.

I've attempted to fix the issue via windows startup repair via booting into windows recovery. I've also preformed a system restore, and executed CHKDISK /R C: from within the windows recovery environment.

What should my next course of action be to resolve this issue?

Comment: But you can navigate the hard drive (`dir` to list the contents of directories, `type filename.ext` to see the contents of text-ish files) in the recovery environment? Also, is the BSOD code `UNMOUNTABLE_BOOT_VOLUME`?

Comment: @BenN Truth be told CHKDISK hasn't finished yet, so I can't traverse the drive as it's currently locked. That said no errors have been found yet, and it's now processing file data; indexes have been verified. I'm pretty sure it's traversable. The error code is in fact `UNMOUNTABLE_BOOT_VOLUME`.

Comment: @BenN CHKDISK completed, no issues to be found. I can mount and browse the volume.

Comment: Before making any changes (and preferably even before running Chkdsk, but fortunately you've had no problems so far), make sure you have all critical data backed up.  It sounds like the problem may be a simple matter of adjusting a small number of sectors involved with the boot process.  However, working with RAID/mirrors in such a way can be particularly prone to have major problems occur quickly, cuasing substantial data loss.  So, get a sufficient backup of any important custom data before doing anything else that may write to the disk.